# How can i keep the value of a variable even after the programm ends?

Tags: c++, variables

I am trying to use a variable value even after the programm runs out....I want to store more accounts using this variable, but everytime i press F9 it lose the value, and start again from 0; I want after the first F9 to increase the value by 1, and the notpad I create with accounts i want to has every account...I am not sure I make myself understandable but maybe someone can help me.

Comment: You can write it to a file perhaps.

Comment: Yes you need some form of persistent storage. Could be a database, but a file would be the most simple place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@André Cascais and @ds4940 are right. Include the fstream library in your program and use ifstream to read a file and ofstream to write to a file. You can also use fstream to do both reading and writing.
Example with text file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in_file{"test.txt"};
    // check if the file opened
    if (!in_file)
    {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open test.txt\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::string str;
    int x{};
    double y{};
    // read the values from file
    in_file >> str >> x >> y;
    in_file.close(); // close the file

    // truncate test.txt
    std::ofstream out_file{"test.txt"};
    if (!out_file)
    {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open test.txt\n";
        return 1;
    }
    // display data
    std::cout << str << " " << x << " " << y << std::endl;
    // write new data
    out_file << str << " " << x + 1 << " " << y + 1 << std::endl;

    out_file.close(); // close the file
    return 0;
}
```

This example assumes you already have the file when the program runs. If you want to read by line use the getline method. Hope this helps!